# User Video Embedding in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, video

I am building an app using Rails 3 that allows users to submit videos.  I would like to be able to accept simply the video URL from the user and using this, my app will generate the appropriate embed code (depending on the video source).  Is there a good library for something like this that already exists? I'd rather not have to reinvent the wheel here and write my own regex/scripts to embed the videos if something already exists.

Think of how tumblr works...you just paste in the url of the video and it embeds it all automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would look into the [embedly api](http://api.embed.ly/) it may be able to address your problem.